# Connection string is sometimes not available in ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Function with a service bus trigger:

```cs
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(
    "%inputTopicName%",
    "%subscriptionName%",
    AccessRights.Manage,
    Connection = "connection")]string mySbMsg)
```

In 99.9% of the invocations, the trigger successfully resolves to a subscription on Azure Service Bus. But sometimes, I see the following error in my log:

```cs
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: UptimeChecker ---> System.ArgumentException: The argument connectionString is null or white space.
Parameter name: connectionString
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.FunctionInvocationFilterInvoker.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__16.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__13.MoveNext()
```

It seems that the service bus trigger cannot resolve the `connection` variable from settings.

I tried to add a debugging filter to my function, in order to find out what is going on:

```cs
public class DebuggingFilter : FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute
{
    public override Task OnExecutingAsync(FunctionExecutingContext executingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        executingContext.Properties.Add("connection", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"]);
        executingContext.Properties.Add("inputTopicName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputTopicName"]);
        executingContext.Properties.Add("subscriptionName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["subscriptionName"]);
        return base.OnExecutingAsync(executingContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

When an error is logged in my function, the properties added to `FunctionExecutionContext` are automatically added to the log message. The weird thing here is that in the scenario where Azure Functions throw this exception, the property values are resolved and shown in the log message.

What could be the cause of this? I've experienced multiple problems with resolving settings from Azure Functions, so maybe it's a general problem?

Comment: what is the nuget version * Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus? did you check Kudu Logs  https://YOURFUNCTION.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\YOURFUNCTION

Comment: It's version 2.2.0 of that package.

Comment: did you try updating to the latest nuget?

Comment: are you testing locally?

Comment: Locally this is always working. The problem only occurs on Azure.

Comment: And only a few times. Works 99% of the time.

Comment: consumption plan or app service plan?

Comment: are you using functions v1 or v2?

Comment: Consumption plan and I'm using v1 for the function in question.

Comment: did you try updating to  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus -Version 2.3.0 I had similar issues that disappeared after updating , also fixing the connection, consumption plan runs on several hosts I am thinking maybe the configuration cannot be read somehow on consumption plan

Comment: I'll try updating and let you know. As mentioned earlier, it works most of the time. So, I'm not afraid that this doesn't work on consumption. But it can be after moving the function to another host or something like that.

Comment: I would suggest , you try this on app service plan and updating the nuget on consumption if it won't work.

Comment: Thanks. Will try both.

Comment: one last resort , re-create the azure function from the portal to re-create the trigger.

Comment: Trigger works fine. Called every time.

Comment: After upgrading to 2.3.0, I get the following error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: what version is your nuget Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host?

Comment: There is no nuget package with that name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a final answer to this question, but I do want to share some details with other people experiencing the same problem. The problem seems to be isolated to v1 consumption based functions only. After upgrading my function to Azure Functions v2 and utilizing the new configuration system available there, I no longer experience the problem above. Since v1 is no longer the current version, I do not want to spend more time debugging into this, when v2 seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

According to this:
you should be using the latest version 2.3.0 for nuget Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus -Version 2.3.0

I would also check if it is an issue when running in consumption plan by hardcoding the connection to see if it is an issue reading the configuration of connection. And otherwise test it on app service plan.

Comment: Version 3 is for Functions v2 as I understand it.